# Retrive date from DateTimeCtrl WXPython

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, datepicker, wxpython

Hey all im having a difficult time with something I believe should be rather simple. Im using WXpython(3.X) to make my GUI and i'm using DatePickerCtrl to form my control. All im trying to do is retrieve the value when I change it. I used the GetValue() method but that only returns the date that currently shows not the one that I changed it to. Then I tried using DateEvent.GetDate but I keep getting an error.

```
def getStartDate(self):
    a = wx.adv.DateEvent(self, self.date_Begin.GetValue(), Event.SetTimestamp()).GetDate
    print(a)
    return a
```

and the error that shows up is

```
**Event.SetTimestamp(): first argument of unbound method must have type 'Event'**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared `def getStartDate(self):` rather than `def getStartDate(self,event):`, so you aren't allowing for the event sent to the function.
There is only one event emitted by this function `EVT_DATE_CHANGED`.

```
import wx
import datetime
import wx.adv
#----------------------------------------------------------------------

class TestPanel(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,None)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

        dpc1 = wx.adv.DatePickerCtrl( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultDateTime)
        self.Bind(wx.adv.EVT_DATE_CHANGED, self.OnDateChanged, dpc1)
        sizer.Add(dpc1, 0, wx.ALL, 50)
        # In some cases the widget used above will be a native date
        # picker, so show the generic one too.
        dpc2 = wx.adv.GenericDatePickerCtrl(self, size=(120,-1),
                                       style = wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL
                                       | wx.adv.DP_DROPDOWN
                                       | wx.adv.DP_SHOWCENTURY
                                       | wx.adv.DP_ALLOWNONE )
        self.Bind(wx.adv.EVT_DATE_CHANGED, self.OnDateChanged, dpc2)
        sizer.Add(dpc2, 0, wx.LEFT, 50)
        now = wx.DateTime.Now()
        print (wx.DateTime.FormatISODate(now))
        print (wx.DateTime.Format(now))
        dpc2.SetValue(wx.DateTime.Now())

    def OnDateChanged(self, evt):
        sel_date = evt.GetDate()
        print (sel_date.Format("%d-%m-%Y"))

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = TestPanel()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Above I reformat the date to dd/mm/yyyy, as I am not from the USA.
If you want more control use `wx.adv.CalendarCtrl`

Comment: I tried this but when I ran it , it say getStartDay missing one 1 required positional argument: 'evt'

Comment: okay I got it to work . it seem if you call the function and add parenthesis like getstartday() it will expect a parameter but when I called it just by the name getstartday it worked fine , thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to bind your `DatePickerCtrl` widget to `wx.adv.EVT_DATE_CHANGED`

Then in your event handler, you would do something like this:

```
def OnDateChanged(self, evt):  
    new_date = evt.GetDate()
    print(new_date)
    return new_date
```

Check out the wxPython demo as it has a good example of this widget as well as most of the others.

Comment: I tried this but when I ran it , it say getStartDay missing one 1 required positional argument: 'evt'